# When the system time zone changes，python datetime.datetime.now() return wrong time！How to solve it！

Tags: python-3.x, timezone, python-datetime

When the system time zone changes，python datetime.datetime.now() still return wrong time！

[image: at 2021-01-29T03:51:48, time zone changed]

[image: but at my app, datetime.datetime.now() still get old time zone's time, until 05:37:33]

Comment: Are you running GNU/Linux in a VM on a Windows host? Do you observe this behavior after changing the system time on the Windows host? What is the output of `cat /etc/adjtime` on the guest machine?

Comment: what do you mean by "*wrong time*"? what do you expect, what does the command return?